# Forward of internal domain to parent public domain (dns)

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I've created local (intranet) domain **local.domain.com**. Now I want to create forward lookup zone to find addresses of my public domain **domain.com** (like office.domain.com) from internal network. However when I create forward lookup zone for domain.com and try to find address www.domain.com I'm redirected to my domain controller instead of public web (which is hosted somewhere else in internet, not in intranet). I'm using windows 2008R2 as my domain controller.

1. So how can I create forward lookup zone for my public domain to have
   it "searchable" in intranet (www.domain.com) or what are the best practices?
2. Is it possible to have domain "internal.domain.com" and in it
   register automatically computers with names of public domain (eg
   computer1.domain.com, computer2.domain.com instead of computer1.internal.domain.com, computer2.internal.domain.com)? If yes how to do that?

edit: I resolved point 1 with adding empty A record with ip of my public web hosting. So if someone have answer for point 2 give it to me :)

Comment: Why do you want your internal DNS server to resolve names for your public domain name?

Comment: I have need to have forward lookup zone for "domain.com" instead of typing "internal.domain.com" in my intranet. So when I have this zone, I must forward www to my public domain.